# Funções no HEREDOC PHP

Tags: php

Eu estou tentando faz um tempo mas não consigo obter o resultado esperado, segue o exemplo:

```
<?php
$titulo = "Título";
$foo = "foo";
function foo(){
    $i = 1;
    while($i <= 10){
        echo $i++;
    }
}
echo <<<EOT
<h1>{$titulo}</h1>
<p>Um texto qualquer</p>
<p>Chamada da função foo() {$foo()}</p>
EOT;
?>
```

Bom no exemplo acima, eu tenho a função foo() com o retorno de um loop, até aí tudo bem, mas quando eu chamo a função no HEREDOC, o resultado retorna acima da string, ele não retorna onde a função foi chamada, ele retorna no início da string, existe um meio de eu resolver esse problema com o HEREDOC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `echo` não funciona como `return`, quando uma string está sendo processada primeiro todos valores e funções são processados, portanto foo() será executado antes da string gerada em `<<<EOT EOT;` exisitr.

Quero dizer, no momento que isso é executado `{$foo()}` o `echo` com HEREDOC ainda "não existe", porque é processado tudo antes para formar a string ou valor qualquer.

O mesmo vale para operações aritméticas, como:

```
echo foo() * bar() - baz();
```

O calculo é feito e só depois devolvido ao echo, para resolver você deve usar return, assim:

```
<?php
$titulo = "Título";
$foo = "foo";

function foo(){
    $output = '';

    $i = 1;
    while($i <= 10){
        $output .= $i++;
    }

    return $output;
}
echo <<<EOT
<h1>{$titulo}</h1>
<p>Um texto qualquer</p>
<p>Chamada da função foo() {$foo()}</p>
EOT;
```

Faça o teste online: https://repl.it/@inphinit/outpur-while-for-in-return#main.php